# Assign value to model property using custom html helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

MY Model is

```
public class FileSelectControl
{
    //property for selected file path value
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@Html.FileBoxFor(x => x.FilePath)
```

Where FileBoxFor is a custom HTML helper class which returns the html (with input tag)

Problem statement :
unable to assign the value in the fileselect textbox to the property FilePath. Say i click on browse button of the file upload control , and select a file, the file path value is not updated to the filepath property.

Here is my Custom HTML Helper

```
    public static MvcHtmlString FileBoxFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        return htmlHelper.FileBoxFor<TModel, TValue>(expression, (object)null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a file input element by using the specified HTML helper and the name of the form field as an expression.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TModel">The type of the model.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TValue">The type of the value.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="htmlHelper">The HTML helper instance that this method extends.</param>
    /// <param name="expression">The expression that resolves to the name of the form field and the <see cref="System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary" /> key that is used to look up the validation errors.</param>
    /// <param name="htmlAttributes">An object that contains the HTML attributes for the element. The attributes are retrieved through reflection by examining the properties of the object. The object is typically created by using object initializer syntax.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// An input element that has its type attribute set to "file".
    /// </returns>
    public static MvcHtmlString FileBoxFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return htmlHelper.FileBoxFor<TModel, TValue>(expression, new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a file input element by using the specified HTML helper and the name of the form field as an expression.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TModel">The type of the model.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TValue">The type of the value.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="htmlHelper">The HTML helper instance that this method extends.</param>
    /// <param name="expression">The expression that resolves to the name of the form field and the <see cref="System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary" /> key that is used to look up the validation errors.</param>
    /// <param name="htmlAttributes">An object that contains the HTML attributes for the element. The attributes are retrieved through reflection by examining the properties of the object. The object is typically created by using object initializer syntax.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// An input element that has its type attribute set to "file".
    /// </returns>
    public static MvcHtmlString FileBoxFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, IDictionary<String, Object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);


        return htmlHelper.FileBox(name, htmlAttributes);
    }
```

Comment: You will need to show your custom helper

Comment: Are you outputting a input of type file in the html helper? The model binder will try and submit the actual file to your controller rather than the file path.